# Installation From Windows (No USB or Disk Support)

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation

I've already partitioned of 86gb from windows and mapped it to F:, how do i go about installing linux to it and then booting to it? i can't find much support for this without the use of a USB drive or a CD

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but try this:

1. Download and install an emulator such as Oracle's [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
2. Setup the emulator for Ubuntu (Create a virtual hard drive, allocate some ram, etc).
3. Tell the emulator to use the iso as a disc.
4. Connect the host path to your F drive as a shared folder to the emulator
5. Start the emulator.
6. In the emulator BIOS menu, tell it to boot from the disc and install Ubuntu onto the virtual drive you needed to make in step 2.
7. After its done installing, try copying the root path into your F drive through the shared folder. (Usually mounted under media if I'm not mistaken)
8. Restart your computer and try booting from your F drive.

EDIT: Make sure your F drive is in FAT32 format.